# How to detect which Fragment I am?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar-compat

Just a question, I'm making an app in android with fragments, that when it opens it loads a list view, when I touch an element it goes to the next fragment and shows me the content, I enable the `bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` to get the back button on the action bar, but I don't know how to return to the ListView Fragment, I'm doing it by this way

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
       {        
          case android.R.id.home:  
              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
              finish();
          default:            
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    
       }
}
```

But it makes this animation like open the window again, it works but looks nasty, also I want to disable the button when I'm in the ListView fragment because there are no more places to go just outside the app, so I want to hide it in the ListView fragment something similar to this:

```
if(this.equals(MainActivity.class)){
//Hide the back button in action bar
}else{
//display ir
}
```

Also i'm using this to make the Action Bar, because I need support for 2.3+ devices:

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
bar.setTitle("Interview app");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to add the `FragmentTransaction` to the backstack using `FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack()`. Then when you press the back or up buttons the previous `Fragment` will be loaded.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

your way is to open a Activity,not a Fragment,and the Fragment has a Method is "replace",you can use it to choose which Fragment that you want!
and you can use FragmentManager's findFragmentById(),to find a fragment

[image]